# Intellij IDEA reformat scala code

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, coding-style

If I have a Scala method declaration too long to fit in a single line, I would separate it in several lines, and my reformat expectations is:

```scala
protected def pruneFilterProject(
    relation: LogicalRelation,
    projectList: Seq[NamedExpression],
    filterPredicates: Seq[Expression],
    scanBuilder: (Array[String], Array[Filter]) => RDD[Row]) = {
  pruneFilterProjectRaw(
    relation,
    projectList,
    filterPredicates,
    (requestedColumns, pushedFilters) => {
      scanBuilder(requestedColumns.map(_.name).toArray, selectFilters(pushedFilters).toArray)
    })
}
```

But after Reformat Code(`control + alt + L`), the output is:

```
protected def pruneFilterProject(
                                  relation: LogicalRelation,
                                  projectList: Seq[NamedExpression],
                                  filterPredicates: Seq[Expression],
                                  scanBuilder: (Array[String], Array[Filter]) => RDD[Row]) = {
  pruneFilterProjectRaw(
    relation,
    projectList,
    filterPredicates,
    (requestedColumns, pushedFilters) => {
      scanBuilder(requestedColumns.map(_.name).toArray, selectFilters(pushedFilters).toArray)
    })
}
```

What are proper code style rules in intellij idea for scala lang should I set to override the default behaviour and get my desired output style?

**Edit**

deselect the `Align when multiline` would result in:

```
protected def pruneFilterProject(
  relation: LogicalRelation,
  projectList: Seq[NamedExpression],
  filterPredicates: Seq[Expression],
  scanBuilder: (Array[String], Array[Filter]) => RDD[Row]) = {
  pruneFilterProjectRaw(
    relation,
    projectList,
    filterPredicates,
    (requestedColumns, pushedFilters) => {
      scanBuilder(requestedColumns.map(_.name).toArray, selectFilters(pushedFilters).toArray)
    })
}
```

Arguments and method body would have same indention(2 space), not the desired one:
argument list with two indents(4 space), method list with only one indent(2 space)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to deselect the `Align when multiline` option in the `Method declaration parameters` section in the `Wrapping and Braces` tab in the `Scala` part of the `Preferences` menu.  You might also want to set the wrapping option in that same section to `Warp if long`.

In order to then get the tabs like you want, you want to set `Continuation indent` to 4 and `Indent` to 2 on the `Tabs and Indents` tab.

Comment: Thank you, I put the result format in answer's Edit section, would you mind help me out again?

Comment: Thanks for updating. I think what I need is only `Method declaration parameters`  `continuation indent` to 4 and other  `continuation indent` to 2. which seems unavailable in Intellij IDEA?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to use Scalariform it is is a code formatter for Scala. It's available as a library, a stand-alone command line tool, or via integrations with various editors and build tools (listed below).

The plan is to add preferences and features as and when people ask for them, so please do raise a Github issue if it doesn't format your code the way you'd like it, and I'll see what I can do.

Scalariform is licenced under The MIT Licence.

If you use sbt,
add this to your project/plugins.sbt

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-scalariform" % "1.3.0")

here is all the information, it is the one that use typesafe in his activator templates,

[scalriform github](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-scalariform)

https://github.com/sbt/sbt-scalariform